# A determinantal mixture of probability densities

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, st.statistics

I came up with this operation after playing with determinantal point processes:

Given two probability densities $f,g$ defined on some measurable space with reference measure $\mu$, set
$$
f\star g(x):=\frac1{2(1-c^2)}\Big(f(x)+g(x)-2c\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}\Big)
$$
where $c:=\int \sqrt{fg}\,d\mu\in[0,1]$; note that the Cauchy-Schwarz (in)equality tels you that $c=1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f=g$, in which case we let $f\star f:=f$. It is easy to check that $f\star g$ is a probability density.

A few comments and first observations:

- Where does this come from? $f \star g$ is the mean density (a.k.a one-point correlation function) of the determinantal point process associated with the projection kernel onto $\text{Span}(\sqrt{f},\sqrt{g})\subset L^2(\mu)$, whence the choice $f\star f=f$.
- $c$ is known as the Bhattacharyya coefficient, i.e. $1-c$ is the squared Hellinger distance between $f$ and $g$.
- $f$ and $g$ have disjoint supports $\Leftrightarrow$ $c=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f\star g=\frac12(f+g).$
- $Support(f\star g) = Support(f)\cup Support(g)$
- For measurable sets $A,B$ with finite measure, we have:
  $$
  \frac{\mathbb 1_{A}}{\mu(A)}\star \frac{\mathbb 1_{B}}{\mu(B)}(x) =
  \frac1Z
  \begin{cases}
  \mu(B) & \text{ if } x\in A\setminus B \\
  \mu(A) & \text{ if } x\in B\setminus  \\
  \mu(A \bigtriangleup B)& \text{ if } x\in A\cap B
  \end{cases}
  $$
  with normalization constant $Z:=2(\mu(A)\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)^2).$

Thus, if you partition $A\cup B$ into the three regions $A\setminus B$, $A \bigtriangleup B$, $B\setminus A$, the probability that the random variable with density $f\star g$ lies in one region is proportional to the surface of the two others.

*Now, the questions: Can you find any other interesting properties for this operation? Is this worth further digging?*

I'm pretty sure there is some more fun hidden with this determinantal mixture...